# Android ListView not displaying

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, listview

In my code I take the data from php page that are in JSON format then I put them in a local database created by SQLite and I want to display the result in a ListView.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ismail.test;


 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
  import android.os.Bundle;

 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;



  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SQLiteDatabase articlesDB;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pharmatList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> adresses = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> tels = new ArrayList<String>();
ListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, pharmatList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"title", "adress", "tel"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
            R.id.adress, R.id.tel});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

  /*  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
           // i.putExtra("tel", urls.get(position));
            // i.putExtra("content", content.get(position));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });*/

    articlesDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("pharmacie", MODE_PRIVATE, null);


    articlesDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pharmacie ( pharmacieID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR, address VARCHAR, tel VARCHAR)");

    updateListView();

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();

    try {
                  task.execute("http://www.pfefes.tk/Pharmacie/pharmacie%20de%20garde/Agdal.php");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void updateListView() {
    try {

        Cursor c = articlesDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pharmacie ORDER BY pharmacieID DESC", null);

        int telIndex = c.getColumnIndex("tel");
        int adressIndex = c.getColumnIndex("address");
        int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");

        titles.clear();
        adresses.clear();
        tels.clear();

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                titles.add(c.getString(titleIndex));
                adresses.add(c.getString(adressIndex));
                tels.add(c.getString(telIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        c.close();
      //  ((ListAdapter) .getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            String pharmacieInfo = "";

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                pharmacieInfo += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(pharmacieInfo);

            JSONArray parentArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pharma");


            articlesDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM pharmacie");

            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);


                String pharmacieTitle = finalObject.getString("name");
                String pharmacieAdress = finalObject.getString("adress");
                String pharmacieTel = finalObject.getString("tel");


                int j = 1;

                HashMap<String, String> pharmaciee = new HashMap<String, String>();

                pharmaciee.put("name", pharmacieTitle);
                pharmaciee.put("adrerss", pharmacieAdress);
                pharmaciee.put("tel", pharmacieTel);

                pharmatList.add(pharmaciee);

                String sql = "INSERT INTO pharmacie (pharmacieID, title,    address, tel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                SQLiteStatement statement = articlesDB.compileStatement(sql);

                String strI = "" + j;

                int k = 0;
                statement.bindString(1, strI);
                statement.bindString(2, pharmatList.get(k).get("name"));
                statement.bindString(3, pharmatList.get(k).get("adrerss"));
                statement.bindString(4, pharmatList.get(k).get("tel"));
                k++;
                statement.execute();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        updateListView();
    }
   }
 }
```

Activity_main

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ismail.test.MainActivity">

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/adress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you receive an error?

Comment: listView not displaying

Comment: Try to change this in listview `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

Comment: no different not displaying

Comment: are you sure the list is not visible? or is it just empty?

Comment: ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, pharmatList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"title", "adress", "tel"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
            R.id.adress, R.id.tel});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);   ==> not empty

Comment: "address" is spelled several different ways in your code. Check the spelling of all data items especially those in your SQL database and HashMaps where the data name is used as a key to make sure that this is not just an issue with a mismatch of data names.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after added elements to the `pharmatList`.